# What is the current «official» way/best practice to train an object detection model using the Tensorflow framework?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

My goal is to use transfer learning to train an object detection model with my own data (bounding boxes) and convert the models to tflite-format.

I did it before, using the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) which was great because it provided a wide range of models to use for transfer learning. But the API is no longer maintained and I want to work with something “up to date”.

So I checked on the TensorFlow page and found [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_object_detection) tutorial but it again uses the Object Detection API, which is deprecated, as stated before.

I also found this tutorial which uses the [TensorFlow Lite Model Maker library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker/object_detection) so I gave the linked Collab a try but I don’t even get past the pip-install because there are some errors regarding the required versions of different packages (we are talking about the official tutorial collab here! And I ran into the same errors when using the code on my PC).

Then there is [MediaPipe](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/object_detector/python) with [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlesamples/mediapipe/blob/main/examples/customization/object_detector.ipynb) When I run the Collab I get a warning.

> “TensorFlow Addons (TFA) has ended development and introduction of new features. TFA has entered a minimal maintenance and release mode until a planned end of life in May 2024.”

So again, some kind of dead end. And when I tried to run it on my PC I had some issues with importing parts of mediapipe_model_maker.

At this point, I am running out of ideas to be honest. I’m “just” looking for a way to use transfer learning with object detection models (especially smaller ones like Mobilenet, EfficientDet). Is there really no worthy successor of Tensorflow Object Detection API? Am I missing something? Some new API I didn't find, some package I am not aware of? I am grateful for any hint!

Comment: https://keras.io/guides/keras_cv/object_detection_keras_cv/